# Name data set as variable in R/Lattice

Tags: r, lattice

Is the filename of the current data set used in Lattice (e.g. in xyplot()) available as a variable name ?

I want to include the data set name as a footnote to the graph and write a generic function that takes the name.

Thanks

Comment: A minimal working example will help get you the best answers. (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean "how do I turn a variable name into a string"?

If so, use the magic incantation `deparse(substitute(my_variable))`.

```
drawplot <- function(x, data)
{
  dataname <- deparse(substitute(data))
  xyplot(
    x,
    data = data,
    main = dataname
  )  
}
drawplot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, iris)
```

---

On second thoughts, that might be overthinking things.  It's a little easier to go the other way: starting with the dataset name, and then retrieving the data with `get`.

```
dataname <- "iris"
xyplot(
  Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length,
  data = get(dataname),
  main = dataname
)
```

Comment: @user1503320 If the answer was useful to you, then you can upvote it by clicking the up arrow next to the tick on the left.